# Qt signals and slots pass by reference

Tags: c++, qt, signals

```
void Scene::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * iEvent )
{
    Square temp;

    emit GetSquareParameters( temp.color.red, temp.color.green, temp.color.blue, temp.size );

    m_Squares.push_back( temp );
}
```

I get mouse coords from `QMouseEvent` and need to get parameters from some sliders of the `MainWindow`. I create signal `GetSquareParameters` in the `Scene` and SendSliderParams slot in `MainWindow`.

Signal and slot are conected like a
`connect( ui->widget, SIGNAL( GetSquareParameters( int, int,int,int)), this, SLOT( SendSliderParams( int, int,int,int) ) );`

I can pass params back by reference for signal and slots ? If not how I can to realize behavior like I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no a signal call is purely 1 way as more than 1 slot may be connected to a signal (and vice versa)

you can either make it a true function call where you can do pass by reference

or create a signal-slot connection in the opposite direction as a callback

Comment: connect( ui->widget, SIGNAL( GetSquareParameters( int &, int &,int &,int &)), this, SLOT( SendSliderParams( int &, int &,int &,int &) ) );
I connect like this, it helped.

Comment: it is not true, it is possible to pass values in opposite direction, see for examples for d-bus in Qt. But this is highly not recommended and it is hard to maintain (bed design). I would avoid this no mater the cost.

Comment: What a design is better in this situation ? It work well but i understand how it's terrible.